# Rails - search and sort based on first letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to list users based on alphabets listing... i.e when I click on letter "A" it
should list all the users starting with letter A, same case for B, C, etc.

For this I am using the code

```
@users = User.search(params[:char])
```

in `params[:char]` I am passing letters (a, b, c, d, etc.).

This code searches for a word with this letter.

Instead I want a list of users starting with perticular letter.

Please can you suggest how to go with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use a SQL like query.

```
@users = User.all(:conditions => "name like '#{params[:char]}%'")
```

See the documentation on [ActiveRecord Finder Methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html) and [MySQL Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) for more information. (Even if you are using a different database, the query should be pretty similar.)

Comment: You might want to add some case insensitivity adjustments to that.

Comment: I would also add an index: `create index name_first_letter_idx on user(name(1))`

Answer (score 3):

For the people that want to search by the first letter you can do something like:

```
 Patient.where('substr(name, 1, 1) = ?', 'm')
```

Correction: I just read the comment for case sensitive so you can include any of the letters case sensitive with:

```
 Patient.where('substr(field_name, 1, 1) = ? OR substr(field_name, 1, 1) = ?', 'C', 'c')
 # there from your controller or model can replace that with
 Patient.where('substr(name, 1, 1) = ? OR substr(name, 1, 1) = ?', letter.upcase, letter.downcase)
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

```
@user = User.all :conditions => ['substr(name,1,1) = ?', selected_letter]
```

Comment: but it compares the letter value, right? so it will search only for downcase letter not for uppercase letter