# Many tables 1 controller, model and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Reworded:

I will have a tables of PlaceA, PlaceB, PlaceC until PlaceZ. Those tables all have the same fields. Problem is, I don't want to use inheritance because it only marked data that it inherits something. And this problem I don't think fit into the concept of inheritance.

When I want to add place Alburqueque, that's begin with A; I will save it into the table A. When I want tot add New York, it will be saved into table N.

And because Rails support DRY, and respect DRY; I want to DRY my controllers (and models, and friends) too. Those tables are exactly containing same fields! When a table is Place is changed structurally, other tables have to reflect the latest changes. That table is only to categorise the first letter, but I don't want to have a category field so that you could tell me to propose combine them all into "Places" table.

So how could I have 1 controller and model and associated views, for 26 tables that have exactly same table structure.

Old question:

I will have a table that I will name it PlaceA to list all places begin with A. Similarly, I will have all the tables for letter A..Z. Now, I already going through the pain of making the models/controllers/views and trying to orchestrate all of them so that actually I can have all those tables, but with just the same models, controllers, and views.

Well, the Controllers can be different anyway if necessary.

I already try using namespace; but I just thinking if there's a better way to accomplish this. Surely I am from Java world.

Comment: why :( this is a serious problem.... why a downvote. I can do easily this on Java, but since I am new to Rail... so help help laaa

Comment: any downvoter should try my problem instead of just downvoting a question. not ethical I guess.

Comment: please help. this problem make me cry, not literally. but seriously it hurts coding.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your grammar, I think you got downvoted due to your english skills and this is kind of a duplicate question. Sorry about that but SO tends to be heavy on native English users. Also your question needs more detail to determine what you're trying to accomplish.

- [setting the table name in the Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4613594/793330)
- [Single Table Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/555668/793330)
- [Or are you doing something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5602808/793330)

Welcome to Rails! Please don't be discouraged!

You might want to check out [Michael Hartl's site](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) for a good introduction. Good Luck

Comment: I already try to look for the entire 1 hour in SO. No, I don't do this for the sake of inheritance. Or perhaps inheritence, but I don't want the data to be saved into 1 table. Place begin with A must be saved into table A. Those tables are similar in nature, but too many controllers/models/views/scripts/scss make my Rails looks ugly.

Comment: If it looks ugly it probably means you're doing it wrong. To me it sounds like you're trying to achieve the third bullet point, but you're forcing it to confirm to a separate model and table for each. The cruft you're referring to is caused by using the scaffold generator. You only need to generate a Model to get the Model and tables created. Good Luck!